# Difference between Legacy Mode and TurboForm mode Dynamic crm online 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-2015

It's there a documentation to get the difference between Legacy mode vs "normal mode" load with turbo form in Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2016.

We actually have some probleme with that and i need to find a source about that.

example.

With IE when legacy are activate, form load are very slow, if not, the process flow are "flicker" with optionset control in the process flow bar

With Crhome, if the Legacy mode is activated, i need to press tab one time to change the focus on each control, when is activated i need to press tab two time.

I could probably write some code to "patch" those comportement, but it's there another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this flickering problem is due to the fact that there is no height specified for the div of the main container of the business process flow. When the optionSet opens, it overlaps the main container height size. The solution for this problem is to set the height of the main business process flow div (div with id "processStepsContainer").  I suggest you create a Web Resources that is a Style Sheet(CSS) and that sets this:

```
#processStepsContainer{
 height: 200px;
}
```

Then you just need to use a link on this style. You can do it using a javascript on the load of a form that calls the FixFlicker function:

```
FixFlicker = function(){
 var head = window.parent.window.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 var link = window.parent.window.document.createElement('link');
 link.rel = 'stylesheet';
 link.type = 'text/css';
 link.href = '/WebResources/theNameOfMyStyleSheet';
 link.media = 'all';
 head.appendChild(link);
}
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

The primary word for the new turbo mode is "async".  There is a lot more stuff that is loaded asynchronously.  Here is a good website that details some of the other differences:

http://www.preact.co.uk/blog/microsoft-dynamics-crm-goes-turbo-with-faster-form-rendering

Comment: Thank daryl, but did you know if there a more technical document?

Comment: I am not aware of something more technical.  Not sure what you're looking for exactly...